What do these instructions say on the LifeCircuit Seated Row?
Can anyone read what the instructions say under "adjust seat"? Thanks.
https://www.encanfnp.ca/files/products/1634053591_20211004_145004jpg.jpg

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a fitness question or anything about using equipment, simply a matter of reading the image.

Adust seat height so that shoulders align with grip.  Lean forward with hips and legs slightly back.
